# Are there infinitely many primes $p_k$ such that $(p_k-1)!+p_k$ is a also prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problem

> I am wondering whether  there are infinitely many primes $p_k$ such that $(p_k-1)!+p_k$ is  also prime. Given that $p_k \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

For a very large prime, I can assume Stirling's approximation. But it doesn't say anything about *factorization* or *Primality* of the number.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? I am almost entirely sure that it is open.

Comment: Well, yes. It's an open problem, I suppose.

Comment: Well since $\sum 1/(n (\log n)^2)$ converges, I would expect finitely many such primes.

Comment: $(p_k-1)!+p_k$ is not divisible by $p_1,\dots,p_k$. It must have a prime factor larger that $p_k$. This proves that there are infinitely many primes, but not necessarily of that form.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: *But not necessarily of that form* ? Which form? And yes, $p_i \nmid (p_k-1)!+p_k$ if $1 \le i \le k$. There are prime factors larger than that which *may* divide $(p_k-1)!+p_k$ if not prime. The probability of finding primes between $p_k$ and  $\sqrt{(p_k-1)!+p_k}$ is what I'm trying to find.

Comment: Not necessarily of the form $(p-1)!+p$. But @leshik is almost surely correct that no one knows how to prove what you ask.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The usual methods of proving the infinitude of such things involves that right. Is there *no* other way?

Comment: There are many ways to prove there are infinitely many primes. They work in different ways, but they do not work by writing down a simple formula like $(p-1)!+p$ and proving that it is always prime.

Comment: We can rule out more and more small factors , but the factorial grows so fast that this does not help much. Even considering the impossible small prime factors, the probability of finding primes of the desired form will rapdily decrease.